# Django administration add user returns Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django

I have deployed my django application to a CentOS server and everything is working fine. I can see the list of users and groups from the Django Administration page. I was able to add/edit users as well before. But now, when I'm trying to add new user, an Server Error (500) is returned. 
Is there any limitations about the number of users can be added using Django Admin page?

Comment: can you add models related to?

Answer (score 0):

run:- python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate if you add any model

Comment: I ran that command and the following message returned: No changes detected.
The problem still exists.

Comment: can you post your models? @user3080720

Comment: I don't know what you mean by posting my models. Actually, I'm not the developer of the app. I just deployed it to the server. It was working fine before. I could add/edit user before from the django admin page, but now I can't.
Should we repost any model?